# PHP - file_get_contents() of a file inside a subdirectory in a zip file

Tags: php

I have a `.zip` file with multiple subdirectories and files inside them. How to use `file_get_contents()` to get the content of a file inside one of the subdirectories of the `zip` file?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without unzipping first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got the Zip extension installed, it should have registered the **zip://** [compression wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php). Try the following:

```
$result = file_get_contents('zip://path_to_my.zip#subDir/foo.txt');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct ways to do this. One is to use to use [Zip wrapper](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) like this:

```
$result = file_get_contents('zip://foo.zip#dirName/bar.txt');
```

Update: The following doesn't seem to work now, not sure yet why. <s>Or you can use [Zip Archive class](https://secure.php.net/ziparchive) like this:</s>

```
$zipFile = new ZipArchive();
if ($zipFile->open(dirname(__FILE__) . '/foo.zip')) {
    $string = $zipFile->getFromName("dirName/bar.txt");
}
```